# Getting the URL in jQuery and creating a post link ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL that looks like....

```
/page/sub/25/ --- edit page with ID @%
/page/sub  ---new page has no ID
```

The last part of the URL is always the ID *(if its not a new page then there is not ID)*.

I need **in jQuery** to get the last part of the URL and send it with the POST. For example...

```
 $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: URLVar, 
                data: "site="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(site)),
                dataType: "json",
                },
```

Where `URLVar` if it has ID is would be

```
page/update/25
```

and if not

```
/page/update
```

**How can I generate URLVar based on the current URL do this?**

Comment: Here's a start: `location.href.split('/')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var href = window.location.href;
var val = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('sub') + 4).replace('/', '');
var URLVar = '';
if (val !== '') URLVar = 'page/update/' + val;
else URLVar = '/page/update';
alert(URLVar);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
   var url = location.href;
    var id= url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Comment: It's a start, but that's not close to a full solution. I usually find it helpful to include some text explaining what code does, too, so that it actually teaches something.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd use a regular expression to search for a number, followed by a `/`, at the end of the string; then form the update URL based on whether or not that matches. You can split that logic out into a function, like so:

```
function getUpdateUrl(url) {
    var matches = url.match(/(\d+)\/$/);
    return '/page/update' + (matches ? '/' + matches[1] : '');
}
```

Then, for example, you'd call it like so:

```
console.log(getUpdateUrl('/page/sub/')); // outputs /page/update
console.log(getUpdateUrl('/page/sub/25/')); // outputs /page/update/25
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Npn2d/)

In your case, you'd probably want to call `getUpdateUrl(window.location.href)`.